# With JPackage on Macos, how can I replace the duke image in the installer with an image of my own choosing?

Tags: jpackage

I've create a mac installation package and used the --icon option to change the icon shown when the app is running.  However, the installer uses a duke image that I'd like to replace with one of my choosing.

[image: Example of the installer's duke image]

Any idea on how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation points out which resources can be overridden. It seems the installer's icon is not amongst them.

A next step would be to ask on the JDK developer's mailing list or read the source code of jpackage. It has quite some gems that never made it into the documentation.

See also

- [Override jpackage Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-405708DC-0243-49FC-84D9-B2A7F0A011A9)
- [OpenJDK JPackage source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.jpackage)
- [OpenJDK JPackage Mac Resource Duke](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.jpackage/macosx/classes/jdk/jpackage/internal/resources/background_pkg.png)